# CSS - Margin collision between 2 DIVs

Tags: html, css

I have two DIV`s and i think I have a margin collision...

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">Example box</div>
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">Example box</div>
```

I have 10px between them, and I want 20px.. Any suggest?

Comment: [Collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Comment: You can work with `padding` instead of margin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As others have already said, this is known as [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins):

> [**8 Box model - 8.3.1 Collapsing margins**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)
>
> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined margin is called a collapsed margin.

In this case, they are sibling elements; therefore the following applies:

> Margins between a floated box and any other box do not collapse (not even between a float and its in-flow children).

Floating one of the sibling elements would prevent the margins from collapsing:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JphMK/)

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">These are NOT</div>
<div style="margin-top: 10px; float:left;">collapsing</div>
```

> Margins of inline-block boxes do not collapse (not even with their in-flow children).

Making an element `inline-block` would also prevent the margins from collapsing:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m565n/)

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">These are NOT</div>
<div style="margin-top: 10px; display:inline-block;">collapsing</div>
```

---

Assuming the elements weren't siblings, you could add `overflow:hidden` to the parent element, as the following would then apply:

> Margins of elements that establish new block formatting contexts (such as floats and elements with 'overflow' other than 'visible') do not collapse with their in-flow children.

Answer (score 1):

then try something like in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/TW236/3/

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 10px; display: inline-block;">Example box</div>
<div style="margin-top:10px;">Example box</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Example box</div>
<div>Example box</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add 20px margin for the first div:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Example box</div>
<div>Example box</div>
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/TW236/1/