# float center or margin: 0 auto; some problems

Tags: css

I wanted my button center inside the main div. I think i have written some position elements incorrectly. Could you help me to solve this problem. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aB3Wq/)

```
<div class='main'>
    <div class='button'>Click me</div>
</div>

.main{
    width:80%;
    height:300px;
    background:#ddd;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}

.button{
    padding: 10px 12px;
    background:#999;
    width:90px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: absolute;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Remove the absolute positioning.

Comment: i removed it is working fine but it is not positioning margin from top with 50px;

Comment: @Tukhsanov: Vertical margins collapse under certain circumstances. Take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove the absolute positioning. You will then notice that the top/bottom margins aren't working. This is because the vertical [margins are collapsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389187/css-margin-collision-between-2-divs/21390126#21390126):

> [**Box Model 8.3.1 Collapsing margins**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)
>
> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined margin is called a collapsed margin.
>
> When two or more margins collapse, the resulting margin width is the maximum of the collapsing margins' widths. In the case of negative margins, the maximum of the absolute values of the negative adjoining margins is deducted from the maximum of the positive adjoining margins. If there are no positive margins, the maximum of the absolute values of the adjoining margins is deducted from zero.

One way to solve this is by adding `overflow:hidden` to the parent element, `.main`. This will establish a [new block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting).

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/M4kLg/)

```
.main {
    width:80%;
    height:300px;
    background:#ddd;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.button {
    padding: 10px 12px;
    background:#999;
    width:90px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    color:#fff;
}
```